# Secret code & Prompt input check

Tags: javascript

Okay, I have a website where I want a secret code (like the konami code) 
so when you press the combination JavaScript will bring up a prompt box 
where you have to enter the right text to continue.

Like so.

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    var keys = [],
        combination = "48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48";

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        keys.push(e.keyCode);

        if (keys.toString().indexOf(combination) >= 0) {
            prompt("Enter something");

            //second code goes in here.-------------------

            keys = [];
        };
    }, true);
};
```

And then the second code I want to combine with the first code.

```
var text = prompt("Enter something", "Here");

if (text != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "You entered " + text + ;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work also when I mess around with the code 
and trying to make it fit in it doesn't work. So what do I do wrong?

Comment: Add the listener on keypress or keyup event instead. Keypress works best for regular 0-z keys.

Comment: If you copy-and-pasted that code, you need a `"` after "something".

Comment: `text + ;` is invalid syntax, aren't you seeing an error in the console for that line?

Comment: Okay can somebody write the hole code the way it will work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you separated your code but this works fine. Notice the extra prompts removed and the `+` at the end of `"You entered " + text;` is removed as well.

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    var keys = [],
        combination = "48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48";

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        keys.push(e.keyCode);

        if (keys.toString().indexOf(combination) >= 0) {
            var text = prompt("Enter something here");

            if (text != null) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You entered " + text;
            }

            keys = [];
        };
    }, true);
};
```